# How to check whether a user has write access to a field

Tags: rest-api

I recently got this error:

```
Faraday::ClientError: INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE: Unable to create/update fields: LeadSource. Please check the security settings of this field and verify that it is read/write for your profile or permission set.
```

I'm using the Salesforce web API (no APEX component), and would like to know how I would find out whether a user has write permission to it.

I'm using the Salesforce ruby gem.

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to do it programatically, you'd need to look at the [Describe Results](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm#apex_methods_system_fields_describe) for each field, and check if it is updateable:

> isUpdateable()
>
> Returns true if the field can be edited by the current user, or child
>   records in a master-detail relationship field on a custom object can
>   be reparented to different parent records; false otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

You can follow these steps

1. Go to Mange Users in Setup.
2. Click on Profiles.
3. Select the system admin profile.
4. Select Object settings.
5. Select the object on whic you want to change or update the access.
6. Click on edit to change the accessebility.